# Filtering selected classes from classification data and Merge multiple images in one, further find out their overlap with polygons, using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to take out the classes having label values 2,3,4 from dynamic world v1 dataset and then want to filter out the polygons overlapping with any of these classes. Currently I tried masking the required classes in separate variables and then merging them, but it's not working.

How do I find out the required output?

For reference,

```
////////////////// Dynamic World ////////////////////////
var dw = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
             .filterDate('2023-01-01', '2023-03-31')
             .filterBounds(geometry);

// Select label layer
var classification = dw.select('label');
var dwComposite = classification.reduce(ee.Reducer.mode());
/////////////////////////// trying to confine the study area to islands//////////////////
var island_geometry= Area.geometry();
var a=dw.filterBounds(island_geometry)
var b= dwComposite.eq(2)
var bb=dwComposite.eq(3)
var merged= bb.merge(b)
var c= dwComposite.updateMask(merged)

print(b.bandNames)
Map.addLayer(b,dwVisParams,"b")
Map.addLayer(c,dwVisParams,"c")
```

Here, area is a vector file generated from the same datasets by filtering, further reference [whole code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fharsh222gf007%2FInternship%3AM2).

Comment: Repository users/harsh222gf007/Internship does not exist.